# Better way of opening a exe from in my c++ app

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Question I am using system call to open an exe with a file associated with it. Even time I click the button that runs this cmd promt comes up. How can I accomplish this without cmd promt coming up or in better terms a better way than using system? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is a legacy app I am sorry...
this will run on windows 7
I'm using VC6 :(

Here is my code cpp..

I have button when clicked it opens a file in a specific exe of mine.

```
void CJunkView::OnCadkeyButton() 
{
      std::string dbdir = "Dir";
      std::string ftt = filenum;
      std::string result = ftt.substr(0, 2); 


      std::string combined = dbdir + result;

      CString fileToOpen = ("\"\\\\CAR\\V3\\Docs\\PRE\\20\\" + combined + "\\" + filenum + ".prt\"").c_str();

      CString exePath = "\"C:\\CK20\\Car.exe\"";

      CString cmd = "start " + exePath + ", " + fileToOpen;

      system (cmd.GetBuffer(cmd.GetLength() + 1));
      //PrintMessage("File Found 2015"); 
}
```

Comment: This is the way how the [`system`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx) function works in Windows. You should perhaps consider the [`ShellExecute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function instead? Or maybe even the [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function directly?

Comment: Use "**spawn**" family of function if you [are on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y988d2.aspx). I can't comment on its state of support elsewhere, but it would be easy to implement a similar version using `fork` and `exec`.